# Unable to broadcast messages from http extender class to App Component in Angular 2

Tags: http, angular

**project Structure**

[image: project Structure]

**Error Information**
This is the error i am getting , when i broadcast the message from http extender service to the app component.

[image: Error Information]

**Loading Interceptor(http extender)**

this is my http extender ,i am unable to broadcast the messages to App component from here ,but i am able to broadcast the messages from the child components to App component ,please see the image for the error information and project structure

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, ConnectionBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { EventsEmitter } from './eventsEmitter';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingInterceptor extends Http {
    private currentRequests: number = 0;

    public constructor(_backend: ConnectionBackend, _defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private eventsEmitter: EventsEmitter) {
        super(_backend, _defaultOptions);
    }

    public get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        this.incrementRequestCount();
        var response = super.get(url, options);
        response.subscribe(null, error => {
            this.decrementRequestCount();
        }, () => {
            this.decrementRequestCount();
        });
        return response;
    }

    private decrementRequestCount() {
        if (--this.currentRequests == 0) {
            this.eventsEmitter.broadcast('loading-complete');
        }
    }

    private incrementRequestCount() {
        if (this.currentRequests++ == 0) {
            this.eventsEmitter.broadcast('loading-started');
        }
    }
}
```

**App Component**
I am listening the events broadcasted in the app component to show the loader gif on the screen

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EventsEmitter } from './assets/scripts/services/eventsEmitter';
import { ToasterService } from 'angular2-toaster';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl:'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    private toasterService: ToasterService;
    private message: any;
    private active: any;

    constructor(toasterService: ToasterService, private eventsEmitter: EventsEmitter) {
        this.toasterService = toasterService;
        this.eventListners();
    }


    eventListners() {
        

        this.eventsEmitter.on<string>('loading-complete')
            .subscribe(message => {
                this.active = false;
            });


        this.eventsEmitter.on<string>('loading-started')
            .subscribe(message => {
                this.active = true;
            });
    }

  

}
```

**Event Emitter**

this is the event emittter i am using to broadcast the events

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

interface EventsEmitterInterface {
    key: any;
    data?: any;
}

export class EventsEmitter {
    private _eventBus: Subject<EventsEmitterInterface>;

    constructor() {
        this._eventBus = new Subject<EventsEmitterInterface>();
    }

    broadcast(key: any, data?: any) {
        this._eventBus.next({ key, data });
    }

    on<T>(key: any): Observable<T> {
        return this._eventBus.asObservable()
            .filter(event => event.key === key)
            .map(event => <T>event.data);
    }
}
```

**App Module**

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule, Http, RequestOptions, XHRBackend, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, ConnectionBackend} from '@angular/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routes';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { LoadingInterceptor } from './assets/scripts/services/loadingInterceptor';
import { EventsEmitter } from './assets/scripts/services/eventsEmitter';
import { ToasterModule, ToasterService } from 'angular2-toaster';






@NgModule({
    imports: [AppRoutingModule, BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, JsonpModule, ToasterModule ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [EventsEmitter,LoadingInterceptor,
        {
           provide: Http,
           useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, eventsEmitter: EventsEmitter) => new LoadingInterceptor(xhrBackend, requestOptions, eventsEmitter),
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
        },{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**I am stuck here for many days, it would be really helpful if you could help me resolve this issue**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `EventsEmitter` dependency within your `useFactory` provider:

```
deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
```

It shoul be:

```
deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, EventsEmitter]
```

That's why your `LoadingInterceptor` constructor gets `undefined` for `EventsEmitter` dependency